# "npm start" doesn´t recompile automatically and doesn´t show code changes

Tags: angular, npm

I am developing an Angular project and everything worked fine until today. I did no changes. But now, don´t know why. the "npm start" command stopped working fine. The project gets succesfully compiled but once I make some change, the compilation doesn´t reload automatically and any change on my code isn´t shown.

I tried to add the `--watch` flag on the `package.json` file like suggested on some sites, but doesn't work.

This is the relevant code on my .json file

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open --host 0.0.0.0 --baseHref=/",

}
```

I can't use `ng serve` because it would fire an error due to the missing baseHref. It is a requirement to make it work this way, with this command, so has been told to me.

Environment I am working with:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.6
Node: 10.15.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.6
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.6
@angular/cli                      7.3.6
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.6
@schematics/angular               7.3.6
@schematics/update                0.13.6
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try adding `--live-reload true`. Also, for some files you'll need to manually stop the run and re-run everything (IE: edit in angular.cli.json file)

Comment: have you tried `npx ng serve --watch --open --host 0.0.0.0 --baseHref=/` ?

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo npm run start` I had similar issue and only for in our team it happened but `sudo` solved issue.

Comment: Thanks, but as provided on details, I am using Windows so can´t use `sudo` .

Comment: furthermore, using sudo to run a node app isn't recommended

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, in Linux. It turned out to be a problem of open files limit:

[React Native Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763428)

Answer (score -1):

Delete the node_modules folder. Run npm install And then, re-run your command npm start

Comment: Thanks but I tested that before posting this question. Didn't worked.