# How to disable file watching in a react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

#### EDIT:

My question is now whether it is possible to launch a react app with react-scripts in a production-like environment where I don't necessarily want changes to files to affect the running react server. check below in Solutions section under C for a brief description on what I have already tried.

I have been struggling with this question for the past two weeks and I am unsure how to proceed. I would like to host my React App on a Node Azure Web App (Linux).

## The problem I am seeing:

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:170
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch 'xxx'
    at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:165:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1274:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/u/work/some-repo/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/u/work/some-repo/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    ...
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! some-repo@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the some-repo@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/u/.npm/_logs/2019-08-30T09_50_59_595Z-debug.log
```

## Solutions attempted:

After reading up on this issue online I have understood that the solution might involve

A: no space on the system. I have checked using `df -h` and looks like there is plenty of space (at least 50% for my machine).

B: file watcher limit reached, this seems to be the problem but unfortunately the Azure Web App is a read-only file system, and running something like `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p` did not help.

C: Disable watching with React. It doesn't appear that I can do this however, if anyone is aware of how to Disable watching with React it would be very much appreciated. So far I have tried `CI=true npm start` to no avail (when I ran command and made a change to a file, the change was actively reflected on my browser: `localhost:3000`

I have also tried adding a multitude of options inside of `node_modules/react-scripts/webpack.config.js` such as:
`watch: false` and `ignore:/node_modules/`.

Thanks,
Nik

Comment: What is the motivation for running the development server in a production environment if you don't want live-reloading? The dev server/react-scripts is not meant to be used for serving a production React app. If it needs to be run in a production environment, why not simply npm run build and host the static assets? And if there is no SSR why does the React app need a separate Node server instead of simply Azure storage, S3, etc. ?

Comment: This is a good idea @adamz4008. All the guides online have been saying to host the entire project on Azure and Azure will run npm start. These guides however are outdated due to a change in Azure, and they do not explain which operating system, which runtime env, etc. That being said, I will be more than satisfied with serving the final build. For this I would need client side routing on Azure Web Apps which I have attempted unsuccessfully with a few different web.config structures. Do you have any experience with this? Added constraint: needs to be Azure web app for company cost benefits.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about Azure. If it says they're running `npm start` automatically I guess they expect you to have your own Express static server to serve the app at the root of the project, just something simple like: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I just ran into this problem and I've got to say that the lack of configuration for the file watching is pitiful.  The "answer" below is horrible and WAY off topic.  This should be governable from webpack.config.js.

Comment: People seems to think everybody is a front end developer. A backend developer looking to run the web app just to make sure stuff still works (because unit tests aren't perfect) should have a way to run things in development mode without hot reload. I keep bumping into ENOSPC errors with no way to change the max number of file watchers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to reconsider your goal `to launch a react app with react-scripts in a production-like environment`.

As `@adamz4008` mentioned, you shouldn't run development server on production. Therefore, you won't hit the watching issue, and you don't need to solve it.

#### Documentation / best practices

According to software development best practices there are different phases of the development.

Facebook React documentation covers them as well.

1. **Develop locally**

   `npm start` / `yarn start`

   > Runs the app in **development mode**.
   >
   > https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-start-or-yarn-start
2. **Build**

   `npm run build` / `yarn build`

   > Builds the app for production to the build folder.
   >
   > It correctly **bundles** React in **production mode** and **optimizes** the build for the best **performance**.
   >
   > The build is minified and the filenames include the hashes.
   >
   > Your app is ready to be deployed.
   >
   > https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build

   **Installing NPM dependencies**

   BTW, usually people run `npm install` before `npm run build` to install all necessary dependencies.

   But I recommend to use `npm ci`. It has deterministic stable results and higher performance.

   https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html
3. **Release / Deploy**

   As your application is just a bunch of static files, you can simply deploy it as static HTML web site to any web server / platform.

#### My experience

In my practical experience with Azure, I deploy React app to a storage account as a static web site (without using/configuring any web server explicitly).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

You can choose any other option.

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir Serykh. This is a thoughtful answer and would work. I will leave the bounty up for a couple more days as my organization has Azure credits that can only be used on Azure Web Apps. If no one is able to provide an adequate Web App solution then we will bite the bullet and proceed with the solution you've provided.

Comment: Don't you have storage accounts? BTW, static web site hosting should be much more cheaper than having running Web App.

Comment: @NikitaJerschow, can you provide any link to conditions of your program? I'll try to figure out something that fits your needs better.

Comment: This answer does not cover anything related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

So something you could do is create the build file and then serve the static files in the directory with a tiny local server.

You could run the `yarn build` then have a script that runs this code `yarn node ./server.js` (or whatever you name it)

This could allow for the performant builds and the server similar to the DevServer that `react-scripts start` server.

I also don't know if you need profiling in production but I added a feature on `react-scripts build --profile` that allows classnames and functions names to persist through the terser.

```js
const express = require(`express`);
require(`dotenv`).config();

express()
  .use(express.static(`${__dirname}/build`))
  .get(`*`, (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/build/index.html`))
  .listen(process.env.PORT || 1234, () => console.log(`__SERVER_RUNNING__`, process.env.PORT),
  );
```

Comment: Let me know if this answer missed the mark. I will try to answer it better.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple case (your app resides in the server root, you have no client-side routing, you don't have to proxy backend calls):

- For the first time, install http-server with `yarn add --dev http-server`
- Build the application with `yarn build`
- Serve the built application with `yarn http-server ./build`

For more complex cases, either use a more advanced webserver like [local-web-server](https://github.com/lwsjs/local-web-server/wiki) or implement the desired behavior yourself using [express](https://expressjs.com) as described in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

To other visitors who are looking for:
Disable node_modules/ folder from watchers by react-script command.

The react (version 17) also registers filewatchers for the big node_modules folder too. In my linux system the default limit was 65k. And there were 110k files in the node_modules directory.

So, I did the following: ([this is the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77284042/14797617))

The Solution is edit the `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`

You should find a pattern like this:

```
const ...

...

module.exports = function (webpackEnv){
    ...
    return {
        target: ...
        ....
    }
}
```

The Solution is to add [watchOptions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionsignored) in return block.

For Example:

```
module.exports = function (webpackEnv){
    ...
    return {
        target: ...
        ....
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/,
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to the author of [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70436159/14797617).