# How do I ignore watching node_modules in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

When I'm running 'npm start', I'm getting the following error:

```
...
...
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/my_project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers'
/my_project/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/my_project/src'
...
...
```

I'm using corporate machines, so **I can't increase the limit for the number of watchers**.

I read online that I should go to 'node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpackDebServer.config.js' and make sure to ignore the node_modules dir.

I tried playing with it the whole day, but still every attempt to run the react app ends up with the same error message.

Any idea how I can overcome this issue? how to make webpack ignore the node_modules?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodemon Error: "System limit for number of file watchers reached"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53930305/nodemon-error-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached)

Comment: Hi @jmargolisvt,

Unfortunately, not really, because the suggestion over there is to increase the limit of file watchers, however, I don't have root permission.
A solution for my problem will need to be ignoring the watching of irrelevant directories.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same answer too. And it took me while to figure out the solution.

The Solution is edit to node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

You should find a pattern like this:

```
const ...

...

module.exports = function (webpackEnv){
    ...
    return {
        target: ...
        ....
    }
}
```

The Solution is to add [watchOptions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionsignored) in return block.

For Example:

```
module.exports = function (webpackEnv){
    ...
    return {
        target: ...
        ....
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/,
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to the author of [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70436159/14797617).

Answer (score 0):

This is inspired by @AbuSufian answer

I added the code to the end of the file to apply the setting.

```js
const prev_mod_exports = module.exports
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
    let exports = prev_mod_exports(webpackEnv);
    let watchOptions = exports.watchOptions = exports.watchOptions || {};
    watchOptions.ignored = watchOptions.ignored || [];
    watchOptions.ignored.push("/node_modules/");
    return exports;
}
```

I'm using devcontainers and hot reloads were extremely slow because the 500K files in node_modules.

I use the below **postCreateCommand** to patch the file in my devcontainer.json
which applies a minified version of the above code if the string **prev_mod_exports** doesn't exist in the file.

```json
{
"postCreateCommand": "npm install && if [[ $(grep -L prev_mod_exports node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js) ]]; then echo 'const prev_mod_exports=module.exports;module.exports=function(webpackEnv){let exports=prev_mod_exports(webpackEnv),watchOptions=exports.watchOptions=exports.watchOptions||{};return watchOptions.ignored=watchOptions.ignored||[],watchOptions.ignored.push(\"/node_modules/\"),exports};' >> node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js; fi && cat node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js && npm run-script start"
}
```