# React: max_user_watches is set to 524288, still showing ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached

Tags: reactjs, react-native, watchman

I have cloned the project and trying to run it for the first time in my system (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) with `npm serve`, but I am getting the following error:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/bs-094/Dev/FPN/fpn-frontend/public'
    at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:165:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1258:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/bs-094/Dev/FPN/fpn-frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/bs-094/Dev/FPN/fpn-frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/bs-094/Dev/FPN/fpn-frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/bs-094/Dev/FPN/fpn-frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/bs-094/Dev/FPN/fpn-frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/bs-094/Dev/FPN/fpn-frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/bs-094/Dev/FPN/fpn-frontend/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/bs-094/Dev/FPN/fpn-frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/bs-094/Dev/FPN/fpn-frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
```

I have looked up the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763428/react-native-error-enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached) & [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11406), but my `/etc/sysctl.conf` has already `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` added in its last line. I have read that 524,288 is the maximum number of files that can be watched. So I am completely clueless on how to listen to my files i.e run my project.

How can I run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As increasing the limit didn't work for me, I tried a different approach. I didn't add my `node_modules` files to the watcher.

From my experience the best fix would be to expose the watcher configuration where one could define to ignore any folders or files of their choosing, not just node_modules.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me! First,

```
$ echo 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

The new value can then be loaded/sourced by running:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: This is already given in the links that I have mentioned in my question. Didn't work for me.

Comment: thank u dud.
Could u explain what does this command ?