# How to update webpack config for a react project created using create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have created a react project using create-react-app. Now I need to update the webpack config, but I don't find the file anywhere.
Do I need to create this file myself or what is the process?
I am new to react and not really sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 48):

No need to run `npm run eject`

**Step 1**

`npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev`

**Step 2**

Add `config-overrides.js` to the project root directory.(NOT ./src)

```js
// config-overrides.js
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    // New config, e.g. config.plugins.push...
    return config
}
```

**Step 3**

'Flip' the existing calls to react-scripts in npm scripts for start, build and test

```
/* package.json */
"scripts": {
    -   "start": "react-scripts start",
    +   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    -   "build": "react-scripts build",
    +   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    -   "test": "react-scripts test",
    +   "test": "react-app-rewired test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

**Step 4**

Restart your app. Done

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: @Butri As the answer is simlified it's recommended for you to check the full [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired). :-)

Answer (score 12):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired

Complete answer is :

**How to rewire your `create-react-app` project**

Create your app using `create-react-app` and then rewire it.

1. Install `react-app-rewired`
   For `create-react-app 2.x` with Webpack 4:

> ```
> npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev
> ```

For `create-react-app 1.x` or `react-scripts-ts` with Webpack 3:

> ```
> npm install react-app-rewired@1.6.2 --save-dev
> ```

2. Create a `config-overrides.js` file in the root directory

> ```
> /* config-overrides.js */
> module.exports = function override(config, env) {
>   //do stuff with the webpack config...
>   return config;
> }
> ```

like this:

```
+-- your-project
|   +-- config-overrides.js
|   +-- node_modules
|   +-- package.json
|   +-- public
|   +-- README.md
|   +-- src
```

for example :

> ```
> module.exports = function override(config, env) {
>     // New config, e.g. config.plugins.push...
>
>     config.module.rules = [...config.module.rules, 
>         {
>             test: /\.m?js/,
>             resolve: {
>               fullySpecified: false
>             }
>         }
>       ]
>
>     return config
> }
> ```

3. 'Flip' the existing calls to react-scripts in npm scripts for start, build and test

from:

> /* package.json */
>
> ```
>   "scripts": {
>    "start": "react-scripts start",
>    "build": "react-scripts build",
>    "test": "react-scripts test",
>    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
> }
> ```

To:

> /* package.json */
>
> ```
>   "scripts": {
>    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
>    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
>    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
>    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
> }
> ```

**Note: Do NOT flip the call for the eject script.** That gets run only once for a project, after which you are given full control over the webpack configuration making react-app-rewired no longer required. There are no configuration options to rewire for the eject script.

4. Start the Dev Server

> ```
> npm start
> ```

5. Build your app

> ```
> npm run build
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the example! Finally something more useful than 'do stuff with the webpack config' from react-app-rewired docs 

Answer (score 9):

## Option 1 - Eject your CRA

If you've just created your app using CRA, and haven't made big changes to it, you could use `npm run eject` - more about it [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject)

Keep in mind that there is no going back (except by commits, of course) after doing this. This will basically provide you with webpack file and other files which are currently 'hidden' in CRA

Some critiques and second thoughts about this method [here](https://medium.com/curated-by-versett/dont-eject-your-create-react-app-b123c5247741)

## Option 2 - React App Rewired

This might be the right choice for you. This allows you to extend your current webpack without ejecting, or messing up / making too many changes at your project as `npm run eject` will. Take a look at the package [here](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired)

A great tutorial by Egghead.io using `react-app-rewired` [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-customize-create-react-app-cra-without-ejecting-using-react-app-rewired)

Comment: An another option can be [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco)

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by running a script between yarn install and yarn build. After yarn install the webpack.config.json file is generated, then immediately run a script on Node that modifies it, and then run the build.

My code:
custom.webpack.config.js

```
const fs = require('fs')

// WebPack.config File
const fileConfig = 'node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js'

new Promise((resolve) => {
   fs.readFile(fileConfig, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
      }
      resolve(data)
   })
}).then((file) => {
    
    let CodeAsString = "Code as String to save"

    let regexCode = /YourCodeRegex}/g

    let result = file.replace(regexCode, CodeAsString)

    fs.writeFile(fileConfig, result, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        console.log('The webpack.config file was modifed!')
    })
})
```

So, now do you need to edit the package.json to include this code in the process:

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "node custom.webpack.config.js",
    "prebuild": "node custom.webpack.config.js",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
}
```

Done! :)

Answer (score 5):

Webpack configuration is being handled by [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts). I assume that you don't want to eject and just want to look at the config, you will find them in `/node_modules/react-scripts/config`

```
webpack.config.dev.js. //used by `npm start`
webpack.config.prod.js //used by `npm run build`
```

Answer (score 5):

You can modify your webpack config or any other node_module using `patch-package` https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Install the version of `react-scripts` you want with `npm i react-scripts@5.0.0`

Then go into `node_modules/react-scripts/webpack/webpack.config.js`. Make the changes you need and then `npx patch-package react-scripts`

`patch-package` will generate a file in your project root like `patches/react-scripts+5.0.0.patch`

Add post-install script to `package.json` with

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    ...
}
```

Now whenever you run `npm i` you will automatically get this patch included with the installed library.

Comment: but what if I update from v5 to v6 later on? won't this react-scripts v6 override my changes?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is:

1. Install `react-app-rewired` and `customize-cra`
2. Create a `config-overrides.js` file in your root folder. Here is an example Webpack override file gist: https://gist.github.com/Nagibaba/209c1bddcc39ff0686a820806cfa8ee3
3. Also, consider that you need to change `react-scripts` inside your package.json to `react-app-rewired` like:

```
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

You are ready to go