# Amplify save environment variables to backend

Tags: environment-variables, aws-amplify

Following [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#amplify-console-environment-variables), I set my environment variable in the console (`$CLIENT_ID`).
In the console I added the echo command to try and insert the variable into a `.env`.

The error I keep getting is `There was an issue connecting to your repo provider`. When I remove the `echo` line the build passes. I've tried single/double quotes and putting the line above/below the other lines under the build commands phase.

Here's the backend section for the build process.

```
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - echo 'CLIENT_ID=$CLIENT_ID' >> backend/.env
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
```

Comment: Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072288/how-to-add-environment-variables-to-aws-amplify).  I think it is what you asked for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add environment variables to AWS amplify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072288/how-to-add-environment-variables-to-aws-amplify)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an comment but to make it easier, I quote from answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072288/how-to-add-environment-variables-to-aws-amplify)

```yaml
build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
        - VARIABLE_NAME_1=$VARIABLE_NAME_1 # it works like this
        - VARIABLE_NAME_2=${VARIABLE_NAME_2} # it also works this way
```

Please thumb up on the original answers, and flag this question as duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a feature request:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4347