# is there a way to use .env react app when deploying to AWS amplify?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, environment-variables, frontend, aws-amplify

I've a react application (generated with CRA) with a `.env` file containing around 10 env variables and I deployed it (react app) using AWS Amplify linked with github. Also I added the same variables (key, value) that I've in `.env` inside `App Settings > Environment Variables` in the aws amplify application. But when I open the link generated it does not use the env variables.

The way I'm accessing those variables is `process.env.{VARIABLE_IN_ENV_NAME}` (as usual). Locally it's working fine, on heroku working fine too but in AWS Amplify I'm not able to make it work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add environment variables to AWS amplify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072288/how-to-add-environment-variables-to-aws-amplify)

Comment: As a complement to the answer posted before, here are more info about env vars https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#access-env-vars