# Error in setting up AWS amplify environment variables, but nothing appears in build. how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am using aws amplify environment variables as follows, but not getting the set variables in the react frontend. I followed various stackoverflow tutorials and ended up with this. I rebuild the project after making changes, did not work..
Would be grateful for the help

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I needed to add REACT_APP_ on every env Variables for create-react-app.
eg: REACT_APP_MUNICIPALITY_NAME,

ref: [How to add environment variables to AWS amplify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072288/how-to-add-environment-variables-to-aws-amplify)