# Create React App: How to use historyApiFallback: true in production

Tags: create-react-app, react-router-dom

From what I understand if you were to create a [react](https://reactjs.org/) app **without** a starter kit e.g [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/), one of things you have full control of is [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

This is comes in particularly handy when you need to solve the problem when your app hits a route before the app is fully loaded.

```
https://your-app.com/login
```

You'll get an error because your routes haven't been created.

So you do something like this:

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
  }
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
  mode: 'development',
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      },
    }),
    new UglifyJSPlugin()
  );
}

module.exports = config;
```

Specifically:

```
   devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
      }
```

So I found this [enter link description here](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) based on this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63280109/how-to-update-webpack-config-for-a-react-project-created-using-create-react-app#answer-63280158)

Any ideas, if there is package or TUT to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?