# Create React App Excluding mapbox-gl explicitly from transpilation

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mapbox, create-react-app, mapbox-gl-js

Only in production using vercel my Mapbox map doesn't work.

This is the error message I get, which links to the mapbox documentation:

> An error occurred while parsing the WebWorker bundle. This is most likely due to improper transpilation by Babel; please see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/install/#transpiling

On the [official documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/install/#excluding-mapbox-gl-js-explicitly-from-transpilation) it says we should select a set of compatible transforms.

> 0.2%, not dead, not ie 11, not chrome < 51, not safari < 10

Which I did, but this did not work:

**package.json**

```js
"production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not ie 11",
      "not chrome < 51",
      "not safari < 10",
      "not op_mini all"
],
```

We can as well use `import mapboxgl from '!mapbox-gl';` to exclude GL JS explicitly from transpilation. Which also gives me an error message.

Or we can configure this centrally in `webpack.config.js` which is not accessible using react-create-app.

Since I do not want to use `react-scripts eject` I installed `react-app-rewired` following this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63280109/how-to-update-webpack-config-for-a-react-project-created-using-create-react-app)

My configuration looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            ignore: ['./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js']
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work either.

Does someone know a sure way to fix this mapbox error? Or is what I have already tried wrong somehow?

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10565)

Comment: How do you know it's definitely mapbox-gl causing issues?

Comment: The link of the documentation is included in the error https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/install/#transpiling

Comment: Ahh I saw that on mobile and didn't scroll! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer searching deeper on the GitHub issue which worked.

[zacharyliu](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10173#:%7E:text=15-,zacharyliu,-commented%20on%2023) commented on 23 Dec 2020

> One workaround for Create React App, where the bundler config is not
> configurable, is to use Webpack's inline loader syntax.
>
> First, install the worker-loader package (yarn add worker-loader).
> Then add the following snippet somewhere in your app, ideally right
> below your imports:
>
> ```
> // eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
> mapboxgl.workerClass =
> require('worker-loader!mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl-csp-worker').default;
> You probably need the eslint-disable line so Create React App doesn't
> error out the build.
> ```

Since I do not use yarn I did

```
npm install worker-loader --save-dev
```

Then on my js file

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
mapboxgl.workerClass = require('worker-loader!mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl-csp-worker').default; // eslint-disable-line
```

The `// eslint-disable-line` comment disables the linter rule for just that line.

Comment: Thank you! I had the exact same problem and this solved it for me as well. I have the feeling that overwriting webworker configs as outlined on the Mapbox help page doesn't work anymore with newer webworker versions because loader options are set differently..