# creating and using a react app on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, npm, visual-studio-code

I can't get a react app installed on my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and not having any success.

I'm in VS Code in the terminal window with node v10.19.0 installed.

I tried once using

```
$ npm cache clean --force
```

before going back to the above steps and got the same result.

Any suggestions? Details follow.

```
$ npx create-react-app
[...]
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.2.1 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.2.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
+ web-vitals@0.2.4
+ @testing-library/jest-dom@5.11.6
+ @testing-library/user-event@12.6.0
+ @testing-library/react@11.2.2
added 29 packages from 77 contributors and audited 1941 packages in 17.132s
121 packages are looking for funding
&nbsp;&nbsp; run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
Removing template package using npm...
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.2.1 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.2.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
$ npm start
[...]
events.js:174
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/hks/Dropbox/old-dog-new-tricks/learn-react-in-x-minutes/public'
at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:165:26)
at Object.watch (fs.js:1258:11)
at createFsWatchInstance (/home/hks/Dropbox/old-dog-new-tricks/learn-react-in-x-minutes/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
at setFsWatchListener (/home/hks/Dropbox/old-dog-new-tricks/learn-react-in-x-minutes/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/hks/Dropbox/old-dog-new-tricks/learn-react-in-x-minutes/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/hks/Dropbox/old-dog-new-tricks/learn-react-in-x-minutes/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/hks/Dropbox/old-dog-new-tricks/learn-react-in-x-minutes/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/hks/Dropbox/old-dog-new-tricks/learn-react-in-x-minutes/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/hks/Dropbox/old-dog-new-tricks/learn-react-in-x-minutes/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
at createFsWatchInstance (/home/hks/Dropbox/old-dog-new-tricks/learn-react-in-x-minutes/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
at setFsWatchListener (/home/hks/Dropbox/old-dog-new-tricks/learn-react-in-x-minutes/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! learn-react-in-x-minutes@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the learn-react-in-x-minutes@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hks/.npm/_logs/2020-12-17T20_50_56_107Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I think I've got it now. Zarko (my T.A. at Springboard) led me to this specific line in the error messages:

ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached

and to this answer to that specific problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55763478

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Take a look at https://bestafiko.medium.com/npm-npm-start-error-enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached-bdc0eab0a159