# facing errors while running npm start or npm run start command

Tags: node.js, npm

I have created a react app through the command line and it started without facing any issues.
But after editing my files in the `src` folder, the `npm start`, `npm run start` both went to a problem.

Here's the ERROR:

```
`events.js:174
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/ruwaid/ruwaid-blog/public/index.html'
at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:165:26)
at Object.watch (fs.js:1258:11)
at createFsWatchInstance (/home/ruwaid/ruwaid-blog/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
at setFsWatchListener (/home/ruwaid/ruwaid-blog/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/ruwaid/ruwaid-blog/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/ruwaid/ruwaid-blog/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:262:21)
at FSWatcher. (/home/ruwaid/ruwaid-blog/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:495:21)
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/ruwaid/ruwaid-blog/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
at createFsWatchInstance (/home/ruwaid/ruwaid-blog/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
at setFsWatchListener (/home/ruwaid/ruwaid-blog/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ruwaid-blog@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ruwaid-blog@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ruwaid/.npm/_logs/2021-01-14T18_29_11_988Z-debug.log`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763428/react-native-error-enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached)

Comment: also if you're using VSCode, add node_modules to VSCode's ignored directories so it doesn't watch the folder and use up watchers.

Comment: @cbr did you mean reinstalling node_modules? If yes, I've done that a lot but still ran into the same problem. I also downgraded my js scripts to `@2.1.8` and worked once

Comment: The problem is that the development server (started by `react-scripts start`) listens to file changes with file system watchers, which on your OS, uses the linux `fs.inotify` API. There are OS limits for the amount of file system watchers, and since node_modules contains a huge amount of individual files, trying to listen to all of them at the same time pops the OS limit for the watchers. The answer I linked earlier tells you how to increase this limit. VSCode also listens to changes to update filenames etc in the file explorer, so if node_modules is not ignored, VSCode will also use watchers.

Comment: If you're not using VS Code, that's fine. Just increase the amount of inotify watchers like in the link I posted earlier.

Comment: I use vs code. And yeah, If I quickly run the npm start in my terminal after booting my Pc, It runs without any error but when I open it in Vscode and after some minutes, running the `npm start` runs to an error

Comment: Always remember the guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it will make your questions much more welcoming to answers, and even keep them from the risk of being closed

Comment: well I've got the issue its with the watch limit. I've increased my watch limitation and now works fine :) Anyways thanks for your kind attention @cbr