# Can't build the sources Jitsi Meet Web version

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I try to develop Jitsi Meet Web version with tutorial:
https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-web/
Sources code: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet
Required mandatory follow above link:

```
Node.js >= 16 and npm >= 8 are required.
```

So, my environment:

```
OS:      Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Nodejs:  v16.19.1
Npm:     8.19.3
```

When I run command `make dev`, it show error messages:

```
.......
./node_modules/.bin/webpack serve --mode development
<i> [webpack-dev-server] SSL certificate: /home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/.cache/webpack-dev-server/server.pem
<i> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Proxy created: /  -> https://alpha.jitsi.net
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: https://127.0.0.1:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet' directory
node:internal/errors:478
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/@atlaskit/tokens/dist/cjs/artifacts/tokens-raw/atlassian-dark.js'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (node:internal/fs/watchers:244:19)
    at Object.watch (node:fs:2296:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:119:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:166:15)
    at NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:331:14)
    at NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:395:23)
    at NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:637:21)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:647:10)
    at NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:645:18) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/@atlaskit/tokens/dist/cjs/artifacts/tokens-raw/atlassian-dark.js',
  filename: '/home/user/Jitsi-dev/jitsi-meet/node_modules/@atlaskit/tokens/dist/cjs/artifacts/tokens-raw/atlassian-dark.js'
}
make: *** [Makefile:125: dev] Error 1
```

So, how can i fix it or get exactly version of all: Node, npm, Jitsi meet on Github... for can build and run the sources successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

With support from Google and chatGPT (:D). I found the answer to this issue. This is related to limited file watchers in Ubuntu. To increase the number to `524288` by following here: [React Native Error: ENOSPC: System limit for the number of file watchers reached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55763478/2506126)

```
# insert the new value into the system config
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

# check that the new value was applied
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

# config variable name (not runnable)
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```