# I'm trying to solve a problem in the execution of my project. When running the yar dev command the following error appears:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, yarn-lock.json

When running yarn dev it always gives the same error when loading the page. I already tried to run it with Yarn Upgrade then Yarn Add Yarn and then Yarn Dev but it didn't run:

Error:

```
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/bruno-adller/projects/frontend/node_modules/moment/src/lib/units/aliases.js'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (node:internal/fs/watchers:247:19)
    at Object.watch (node:fs:2343:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/bruno-adller/projects/frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:119:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/bruno-adller/projects/frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:166:15)
    at NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/bruno-adller/projects/frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:331:14)
    at NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/bruno-adller/projects/frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:395:23)
    at NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (/home/bruno-adller/projects/frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:637:21) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/home/bruno-adller/projects/frontend/node_modules/moment/src/lib/units/aliases.js',
  filename: '/home/bruno-adller/projects/frontend/node_modules/moment/src/lib/units/aliases.js'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**info Visit** https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

When running yarn dev it always gives the same error when loading the page. I already tried to run it with Yarn Upgrade then Yarn Add Yarn and then Yarn Dev but it didn't run:

When running the project it loads but then stops and the above error appears and the website does not open.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763428/react-native-error-enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown because the number of files monitored by the system has reached the limit. You can check the solution given here.
[React Native Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763428/react-native-error-enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached)